# PHP - For each to get variable based on $i

Tags: php

I'm having some doubt doing some for each loop, so i have an immense variable names ranging from $a1 - $a120 
What I'm trying to do is doing a for each loop from where I can get each of thoose by using an indexing system.

```
$a116= "N69";
$a117= "V52";
$a118= "V53";
$a119= "V54";
$a120= "V55";


# FIM 

for ($i = 0; $i <= 119; ++$i) {

   $var = ${"a".$i}; // This is what i need to learn to do 
   $sheet->setCellValue($var, $array[$i]); // the array is other information im inserting to the file


}
```

Comment: When you have variable like `$a1, $a2`... etc that is a good indication that you need to use an array.

Comment: What doesn't work with the code you've posted? If `$a1` up to `$a115` actually exist then this looks like it should work fine. Although admittedly it doesn't look like a very good structure.

Comment: In regards to `where i can get each of thoose by using an indexing system` you've practically spelled out an array's entire life story and purpose in this world.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion guys, that was really dumb of me not even thinking about the array...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not good for the loops. But you can use it, if you can not change your codes.

I just added

```
$var_name="a".$i;
$var = $$var_name;
```

And the full code is below.

```
$a116= "N69";
$a117= "V52";
$a118= "V53";
$a119= "V54";
$a120= "V55";


# FIM 

for ($i = 0; $i <= 119; ++$i) {
   $var_name="a".$i;
   $var = $$var_name; // This is what i need to learn to do 
   $sheet->setCellValue($var, $array[$i]); // the array is other information im inserting to the file


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should update the code to use an array.

```
$data = [];
$data["a116"] = "N69";
$data["a117"] = "V52";
$data["a118"] = "V53";
$data["a119"] = "V54";
$data["a120"] = "V55";
```

Now you can use a foreach loop getting the key/value pairs

```
foreach($data as $key => $value){
    $sheet->setCellValue($key, $value);
}
```

Comment: I think that variables such as `$a[116] = "N69";` would be more appropriate.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus those are cell names from what I can tell. The OP would have to concatenate a onto each of those like they are trying to do now. Using `$data` will allow them to move about to say b,c,d just by updating keys.

Comment: In that case, I would go for `$data[ 'a' ][ 116 ]` instead of the flat structure you show because it will avoid the need for parsing out the column from the row if you needed to use that info separately.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus that is your preference. This is mine ;) and done on short notice. I see the advantage of that,

Comment: That's cool. You will love yourself when `$data["b76"] = "G745";` is needed and then need to find out how many rows you have in column `a`

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I said I see the advantage of your solution. I had already changed their approach enough I did not want to add too many extra layers. It comments like these that make this site not worth helping.